# Is Rational number under multiplication group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

A binary operation $*$ is defined on $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $a*b=ab$.

So, it is just simple multiplication.

I found out that this is a group with identity $=1$ and inverse is reciprocal of element "$a$" in $G$.

But, my answer key says that this is not a group because axiom 3 (inverse) fails.

I can't see why it is not a group.

Is my answer key wrong or am I wrong?

Answer (score 13):

HINT: What is the multiplicative inverse of $0$?

If we replace $\mathbb Q$ with $\mathbb Q\setminus \{0\}$ to exclude $0$ from our set, under the operation of multiplication, we do then have a group: $(\mathbb Q\setminus \{0\}, \cdot)$

Comment: are you saying that 0 is in Rational number and inverse of 0 is not defined cause 1/0 is undefined

Comment: Pretty much. Remember the definition of the inverse of an element: If $b$ is the inverse of $a$ in a group G, then $a*b = b*a = e$ where $e$ is the identity element. With our group, that identity element is $e = 1$. But there is no element $a \in \mathbb Q$ such that $a(0) = (0)a = 1$.